# How can I speed up SQL queries using CSharp SQLite?

Tags: c#, performance, sqlite

**Background:**
I have a SQLite3 database and I am using [CSharp SQLite](http://code.google.com/p/csharp-sqlite/) to query data. My problem is that any queries with JOIN or ORDER BY calls are really slow (0.1 sec using `CSharp-SQLite` vs 0.003 sec using orig. `SQLite`).

The latest [benchmarks](http://code.google.com/p/csharp-sqlite/wiki/Benchmarks) for CSharp SQLite indicate that it is at most 2x slower, which would be fine, but I'm getting times that are 30x slower.

Now, I have indexed all the necessary fields in my database and have the appropriate Primary and Foreign keys. Plus, the original SQLite runs these queries fine.

**Question:**
I have to use a managed code port of SQLite, so is there something I'm missing here or a call I need to make to `CSharp SQLite`? Is there an alternative SQLite library port out there somewhere?

Comment: Do you need a full port, or do you just need to be able to easily use SQLite from C#? [System.Data.Sqlite](http://sqlite.phxsoftware.com/) is an ADO.NET wrapper around standard SQLite.

Comment: Full port. System.Data.SQLite, as a wrapper around the C++ code, still requires the C++ runtimes. We can't use anything that uses those runtmes.

Comment: Gotcha.  Just from looking at the benchmark code, it seems to only cover very basic queries. There aren't any JOIN or ORDER BY clauses in the test queries. Perhaps C#-SQLite really is slow in that department?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This precise question was asked in the [Csharp-sqlite forums](https://groups.google.com/forum/?hl=en-GB&fromgroups#!topic/csharp-sqlite/f8v7yTLPlMk) and the successful solution was to remove the SQLITE_ENABLE_OVERSIZE_CELL_CHECK flag at compile time. This is a DEBUG flag that results in unneeded but intensive calculations.