# speed up SQLite queries working with C# or to disable SQLITE_ENABLE_OVERSIZE_CELL_CHECK

Tags: c#, sql, sqlite

My question is how to speed up a SQLite query working C#? 
I am working with ADO.NET 2.0, visual studio 2010

I have read that a solution could be:
Disable SQLITE_ENABLE_OVERSIZE_CELL_CHECK flag 
from 
[How can I speed up SQL queries using CSharp SQLite?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10643309/how-can-i-speed-up-sql-queries-using-csharp-sqlite)

But I do not know how to do so, in my project properties form visual studio:
Project-> properties-> build-> Conditional Compilation symbols is empty.
¿is there other way to disable the flag?
¿is there other way to improve sqlite/c# performance?

I am using a complex query that has an imediate response in SQLiteManager, but it gets stuck (2 minutes) either using DataReader or DataSet.

```
SQLiteCommand command  ...
var table = new DataTable();
using (var r = command.ExecuteReader())
table.Load(r);
```

or

```
SQLiteDataAdapter adapter ... ;
DataSet solution = new DataSet();
adapter.Fill(solution);
```

The table I am consulting is around 20,000 rows, but the query result could return empty or a few rows.

EDITED:
It seems to be related with the number of records of the table and it doesn't make sense to me. But the same query with a small number of rows table has a good time however a table with  more than 14,000 rows seems to wasting time somewhere (And not related with the number of wors that returns the query)

Thanks in advance